# Algorithm for certain permutaion of array elements (parallel sorting by regular sampling) [C++]

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

I am implementing an parallel sorting by regular sampling algorithm which is [described here](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/download/attachments/99155993/Sort+ParaProg%28Quinn%29chpt14.5.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1203641170000). I am stuck in a point at which I need to migrate sorted sublists to proper places of the sorted array. The problem can be stated in that way: There is one global array. The array has been divided into p subarrays.Each of those subarrays was sorted. p-1 global pivot elements were determined and each sub-array was divided into p sub-sub arrays (yellow, red, green). Now I need to move those sub-sub-arrays so that sub-sub-arrays with local index i are in the thread i (so they are ordered in such manner at which colors are neighbouring and the order from left to right remains).

Actually serial algorithm will do, but I just have no clever idea how to obtain a proper permutation. The following figure shows a case for p=3 threads. Yellow color denotes a sub-sub-array 0, red - 1, green - 2.

[image: problem visualization]

The sub-sub arrays may have different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Seems like I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, so I shall take the route of posting the answer.

So let me get this straigh. You are stuck on phase 3 of this algo. Right?

---

How about this:

Let's have p linkedLists of indexes. Let each process communicate the index ranges to process i; as the indexes are communicated, append the indexes to list of process i. When all the communications are over, you shall have the all the indexes for process i in the list of process i. Node of this list should be a data structre like

```
 Node {
      index
      valueOfIndex
 }
```

Now as you populate the list, copy its value also in the list.

Once you are through with the process. You can recrate your array for process i using its list i.

????